# Error during install of lzip on MacOS 10.11.6

Tags: install, unix

This is probably overly obvious but I am stuck. How can I complete the last leg of this install? If someone can explain what I am being told in the error after "make install" it would be helpful.

```
Last login: Sun Jul  9 13:54:14 on ttys000
Funi:~ $ cd /Users/ezx/Applications/Lzip
Funi:Lzip ezx$ ls
lzip-1.19       lzip-1.19.tar.gz    lzip-1.19.tar.gz.sig
Funi:Lzip ezx$ cd lzip-1.19
Funi:lzip-1.19 ezx$ ls
AUTHORS     Makefile.in arg_parser.h    doc     encoder_base.h  file_index.h        testsuite
COPYING     NEWS        configure   encoder.cc  fast_encoder.cc list.cc
ChangeLog   README      decoder.cc  encoder.h   fast_encoder.h  lzip.h
INSTALL     arg_parser.cc   decoder.h   encoder_base.cc file_index.cc       main.cc
Funi:lzip-1.19 ezx$ man apt-get
No manual entry for apt-get
Funi:lzip-1.19 ezx$ ./configure

creating config.status
creating Makefile
VPATH = .
prefix = /usr/local
exec_prefix = $(prefix)
bindir = $(exec_prefix)/bin
datarootdir = $(prefix)/share
infodir = $(datarootdir)/info
mandir = $(datarootdir)/man
CXX = g++
CPPFLAGS = 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -W -O2
LDFLAGS = 
OK. Now you can run make.
Funi:lzip-1.19 ezx$ make
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -c -o arg_parser.o arg_parser.cc
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -c -o file_index.o file_index.cc
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -c -o list.o list.cc
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -c -o encoder_base.o encoder_base.cc
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -c -o encoder.o encoder.cc
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -c -o fast_encoder.o fast_encoder.cc
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -c -o decoder.o decoder.cc
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -DPROGVERSION=\"1.19\" -c -o main.o main.cc
g++  -Wall -W -O2 -o lzip arg_parser.o file_index.o list.o encoder_base.o     encoder.o fast_encoder.o decoder.o main.o
Funi:lzip-1.19 ezx$ make install
if [ ! -d "/usr/local/bin" ] ; then install -d -m 755 "/usr/local/bin" ; fi
install -m 755 ./lzip "/usr/local/bin/lzip"
install: /usr/local/bin/lzip: Permission denied
make: *** [install-bin] Error 71
Funi:lzip-1.19 ezx$
```

Answer (score 1):

You're logged in as an ordinary user which do not have write permissions for system folders like /usr/local/bin/.

Normally you'll run the last command like this:

```
sudo make install
```

This means that the "make install" command should be executed with administrative privileges - and thus having write permissions for system folders.

Alternatively you can rerun the configure command giving it a bindir that is inside your own home directory. Then you can install the binary to there, but you'll then have to specify full path to the binary every time you want to run it.

Comment: Just ran it and got:

if [ ! -d "/usr/local/bin" ] ; then install -d -m 755 "/usr/local/bin" ; fi
install -m 755 ./lzip "/usr/local/bin/lzip"
if [ ! -d "/usr/local/share/info" ] ; then install -d -m 755 "/usr/local/share/info" ; fi
rm -f "/usr/local/share/info/lzip.info"*
install -m 644 ./doc/lzip.info "/usr/local/share/info/lzip.info"
if /bin/sh -c "install-info --version" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then \
  install-info --info-dir="/usr/local/share/info" "/usr/local/share/info/lzip.info" ; \
 fi

Comment: if [ ! -d "/usr/local/share/man/man1" ] ; then install -d -m 755 "/usr/local/share/man/man1" ; fi
rm -f "/usr/local/share/man/man1/lzip.1"*
install -m 644 ./doc/lzip.1 "/usr/local/share/man/man1/lzip.1"

Comment: It's hard to read that in the comments - but there's no errors in that. So if that run to completion like that, you now have the program installed.

Comment: Seems like it's trying to guide me to do something though and I have no idea what that is.

Comment: No, it is not trying to guide you. It just installed the program and its associated manual pages.

Comment: so it's just telling me where stuff was installed then?

Comment: Not really. It is just displaying the commands that it runs. For example to create a directory with specific permissions, removing files, copying files, etc.